# How to make facebook custom story with custom structure like strava?

Tags: facebook, feed

I understand that we can make custom facebook feeds with custom actions and objects (doc: [facebook custom stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started))

However, I can't seem to find any documentation about making a custom-structured output feed like Strava below for example. Just to clarify, the miles, minutes, mins/mi and elevation info are not part of the image; it's a table tag. (also, the route in the image seems to be SVG)

Edit: I don't have enough stackoverflow reputation to post an image, so here is the imgur link:

[Strava feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2G2w.png)

Comment: have same concern. Anyone know the answer?

Comment: found it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness